# Socket io connected at same time with same socket.id

Tags: node.js, dart, socket.io

I developing chat app using socket io. The problem is when two socket connected at same time will produce same socket.id. So when socket disconnect, it will remove both socket. so the other one cannot listening anymore. How i can prevent socket connected with same id? Thank You.

```
app.post("/online", bodyP, async (req, res) => {

var userID = req.body.username;
var connectStatus;

try {
  if (onlineUsersArray.indexOf(userID) === -1) {

    connectStatus = true;
    var io_online = io.of("/online");

    io_online.on("connection", async function (socket) {

        var date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Singapore" });
        onlineUsersArray.push(userID.toString());

          users[socket.id] = userID;
          console.log('sessionID ' + socket.id);
          console.log(users[socket.id] + " connected at " + date);
          console.log("User in array : " + onlineUsersArray);
          console.log("Number of users connected : " + onlineUsersArray.length);

          socket.on("disconnect", function () {
            var date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Singapore" });

            if (onlineUsersArray.indexOf(users[socket.id]) === -1) {
              console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + users[socket.id] + "Not existed in online array");
            } else {
              var indexOfConnection = onlineUsersArray.indexOf(users[socket.id]);
              onlineUsersArray.splice(indexOfConnection, 1);

              console.log("user " + users[socket.id] + " disconnected at " + date);
              console.log("Number of users connected : " + onlineUsersArray.length);
              console.log("Users Currently Online: " + onlineUsersArray);
            }
            socket.removeAllListeners();
            io_online.removeAllListeners();

          });

    });
  } else {
    console.log("user " + userID + " already in session");
    connectStatus = false;

  }

  res.status(200).send({
    status: true,
    connection: connectStatus
  });
}
catch (e) {
  res.status(200).send({
    status: false,
    result: "Failed to set online user"
  });
  logg.loggerServer("app.js - Online user error ", "0", "Failed in online " + e);
}
```

});

if 2 or more device run at same time it will produce same socket id

Comment: Two connecting sockets do not produce the same socket.id so you likely have some other problem in your code that is confusing the two sockets.  We could perhaps help you with that other problem if you showed the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Oh I've never see this. so you say inside io.on('connect', (socket) => {` here socket.id's are same with another connection? Maybe you write on `id` property?